# How electronic components keep synchronized?

Tags: synchronous

So, voltage travels super fast right? Still, there has to be some lag between voltage traveling from one transistor into another. How is a circuit kept synchronized then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The need to ensure that signals arrive at the proper time is the core of what it means to design a digital circuit, including processors, memory etc.  IF two signals need to be present for a system to then change it's operation and one of those signals arrives late, then the system does not work.

THere are several ways that this is accomplished.  The dominant method (99 + %) is through the use of synchronous logic, also called clocked logic.  There is a central time base  called a clock that initiates activity and the system is carefully designed so that all the signals are in place and settled and ready for when the next "tick" of the clock arrives.  This system is simulated by varying, the speeds of the transistors, the operational voltage and the temperature to ensure that under all conditions the signals will arrive before the next clock tick.  These simulations take into account the actual placement of the devices on the die and how heavily loaded the signals are.  A transistor that is further away will get a signal later, a more heavily loaded sinal will respond more slowly.

There are many circuit solutions to help the designer accomplish her "timing closure".

Answer (score 0):

Wavelength is what matters here. Generally, the relationship is \$\lambda=\dfrac{c}{f}\$ where \$\lambda\$ is wavelength in meters, c is the speed of light, and f is frequency in Hz. For low frequency and, breadboard or PCB, the wavelengths are long enough to consider the difference in voltage negligible. It's a bigger deal at RF frequencies. 60Hz has a wavelength from NYC to LA, 2.4 GHz however, has a wavelength of a few inches.

For high frequency applications, everything needs to be kept as small and close together as possible. This is why you see tiny surface mount components in smart phones and Wifi gadgets. Also, if you look at a computer's motherboard, you may see a trace that just zig-zags back and forth before reaching its destination. The zig-zag is literally a delay to ensure two signals arrive at their destination simultaneously.

Comment: It satisfies me the way we just have to deal with it and make delays through extra wire.

Comment: That isn't always true, it only applies at high frequencies.